# php coding Form submission to server using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have typed this coding by using php and mysql. In If statement condition  Id part is not  inserted into database. But other fields are inserted into database. I couldn't find out the error. Can anyone tell what is the error?

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","database","user") or die("unable to connect");
    //echo "Connected Successfully";
    ?>
    <h2>Form Submission to Server</h2>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {// get user inputs

    $error="";
    $resultmessage="";      
    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    //error messages
    $missingfirstname="<p>Enter your First name</p>";
    $missinglastname="<p>Enter your Last name</p>";
    $missingemail="<p>Enter your Email id</p>";
    $invalidmail="<p>enter your valid mail id</p>";
    $missingpwd="<p>Enter your password</p>";
        if(!$firstname)
        {
            $error.=$missingfirstname;
        }
        else
        {
            $firstname=filter_var($firstname,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
        if(!$lastname)
        {
            $error.=$missinglastname;
        }
        else
        {
            $lastname=filter_var($lastname,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }

        if(!$email)
        {
            $error.=$missingemail;
        }
        else
        {
            $email=filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {
                $error.=$invalidmail;
            }
        }
        if(!$password)
        {
            $error.=$missingpwd;
        }
        if($error)
        {
            $resultmessage='<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$error.'</div>';

            echo $resultmessage;
        }

        else
        {
            //no errors,prepare variables for query
            $tblname="attend4";
            $firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$firstname);
            $lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$lastname);
            $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);
            $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
            $password=md5($password);

            //execute the query
            if(!$id)
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO attend4(firstname,lastname,email,password)VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";          
            }
               else
               {
                   $sql="INSERT INTO attend4(id,firstname,lastname,email,password)VALUES('$id',$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";

               } if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
                 {
                    $resultmessage="Data added successfully";
                    echo $resultmessage;
                 }

                 else
                 {
                     $resultmessage="unable to add";
                     echo $resultmessage;
                  }

              }

          }

          ?>
          <form action="33.populateusigform.php" method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="number">Number</label>
              <input type="number" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" maxlength="4" placeholder="Enter your Number"> 
              </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" maxlength="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Firstname">

              </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
              <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter your lastname" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter your Email Id"class="form-control">
                  </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter your Password" class="form-control">
              </div>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block" value="Send data">

          </form>
```

Comment: is your table field (auto increment id)is different from your html id?

Comment: Could you show us your DB schema?

Comment: `ifempty($email)` is better to check input field required than `if(!$email)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is with the `if($id)` which may act strangely if given 0, triggering the sql query without the id term.

I would use `if(empty($id))` instead it will be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Too many problems...

1) you have kept your action "33.populateusigform.php" for form but are inserting data from same file....

2) have you kept your id to auto increment?

3) what is use to save id in your case, it will automatically be saved if you use as primary key in db.

Need to check your db schema for further assistance.